# From what function do come the gradients that I use to adjust weights?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, gradient-descent, fastai

I have a question about the loss function and the gradient.

So I'm following the fastai (https://github.com/fastai/fastbook) course and at the end of 4th chapter, I got myself wondering.

**From what function do come the gradients that I use to adjust weights?**

I do understand that loss function is being derivated. But which? Can I see it? Or is it under the hood of PyTorch?

Code of the step function:

```
def step(self):
    self.w.data -= self.w.grad.data * self.lr
    self.b.data -= self.b.grad.data * self.lr
```

So I'm interested in the origin of `w.grad/b.grad`.

Comment: The `grad` attributes are the gradients of the loss with respect to that variable (i.e. the weights and biases). The typoe of loss function used depends on the specific use case, this can for example be a mean squared error loss function or a categorical loss function. I am not sure if you have a specific example in mind, but the section 'Step 3: Calculate the loss' of [this notebook](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/master/04_mnist_basics.ipynb) shows how the loss is calculated, where in this case it is using the mean squared error (mse) loss function.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I think I found the place where I can try to understand this.
Long story short, it is necessary to derive the whole sequence of functions used to get full loss derivative.
Here is the source: https://github.com/stephencwelch/Neural-Networks-Demystified/blob/master/Part%204%20Backpropagation.ipynb